# Downloading data from URL using Jsoup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsoup

I am tring to get .csv file from a url, when i loop through the links using the "a" tag, the href that i want doesn't exist. how can i get it's href.

```
    `    String URL = internalConstant.getMlcuURL();
    String ffiListFile = null;
    logger.info("Page URl: " + URL);
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

            logger.info("Elements aaaa"+ link);

            String absHref = link.attr("abs:href");
            if (absHref.endsWith(".csv")) {

                logger.info(absHref);
                ffiListFile = absHref;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (ffiListFile.isEmpty()) {
            logger.error("file not found");

            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "MLCU File not found in website");
        }

        this.fileDownloadFFIListService.downloadExcelFile(ffiListFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("download error " + e.getMessage());
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Failed to download file");
```

`

Comment: how about just `doc.select("a")`?

Comment: it gives the "a" without the href

Comment: this is the page Source  I'm trying to read, view-source:https://apps.irs.gov/app/fatcaFfiList/flu.jsf
and the "a" of .csv (25.1)

Comment: When you take a look at webpage source (CTRL+U in the browser) and search for `FFIListFull.csv` you'll see this filename is included in Javascript code. After your browser renders the page it executes Javascript to dynamically fill these hrefs. Jsoup can't execute Javascript so in this case you can't use it to achieve what you want. [Selenium webriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) can do this.